# How to decrease latency on Binance API /api/v3/order calls?

Tags: vb.net, binance

I made a triangular arbitrage program in VB.NET using Binance API.
When I call `/api/v3/depth` it takes about 20ms, but when I call `/api/v3/order` it often takes about over **1000ms.**

Is there a way to decrease latency with `/api/v3/order`?

The order is MARKET (not LIMIT, STOP_LOSS and so on).

Example:

`api.binance.com/api/v3/…` often takes about over 1000ms.

`api.binance.com/api/v3/depth?symbol=LTCUSDT&limit=10` takes about 20ms.

I want to decrease the latency. Is there anything I can do?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question could possibly benefit from some code snippets and more details on how you are calling the APIs.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Example, I call this API.
https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?symbol=LTCUSDT&side=BUY&type=MARKET&quoteOrderQty=60.0&recvWindow=100&timestamp=1618890891713&signature=xxxxx
It's often takes about over 1000ms.

But this api takes about 20ms.
https://api.binance.com/api/v3/depth?symbol=LTCUSDT&limit=10

I use VB.NET.
I want to decrease that's latency. Is there anything I can do?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, yes I recommend that you edit your original question to include the additional details you placed in the comment. You stand a much better chance of getting a solution from an expert experienced in this API if the original question has full additional details. Comments can easily be overlooked as people surf questions that they're able to answer. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hi Jeff Mergler, thank you for your advice.
I added example to original Question.

Comment: Hi Jeff Mergler, Thank you for editing my question text. I'm not good at English. Thanks.

Comment: Did you reach any solution? I'm suffering the same slow response from these endpoints especially when it comes to the market depth data. It seems that it only updates once a second.